# Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function call() in PHP

Tags: php

I am a beginner in `PHP` and `MySQL`. Here I am in stuck in one of the problem namely

> Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function call() in PHP

in my developing application. Below is the code sample of the specific problem.

```
//  get the user id from the db
   $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM doctor_specialist WHERE username = ? ");
   $stmt->bind_param("s",$doctor_name);
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   if($result->num_rows > 0){
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   
   $user_id = $row['user_id'];

  //  check the time slots whether it is available
  $stmt9 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM doctor_schedule WHERE user_id = ?  AND DATE_FORMAT(end_time,'%Y-%m-%d')  = ? ");
  $stmt9->bind_param("ss",$user_id,$date);
   $stmt9->execute();
   $result9 = $stmt9->get_result();
   if($result9->num_rows > 0){
     while($row = $result9->fetch_assoc()) {

      $end_times_doctor = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', strtotime($row['end_time']));

   }

  }

  //  check the time slots whether it is available
  $stmt10 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM patient_schedule WHERE user_id = ?  AND  DATE_FORMAT(end_time,'%Y-%m-%d')  = ? order by end_time DESC LIMIT 1 ");
  $stmt10->bind_param("ss",$user_id,$date);
   $stmt10->execute();
   $result10 = $stmt10->get_result();
   if($result10->num_rows > 0){ 
     while($row = $result10->fetch_assoc()) {

      $end_times_patient = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', strtotime($row['end_time']));
      $time_interval = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+15 minutes',strtotime($row['end_time'])));

    }

    $diff = strtotime(date($end_times_doctor)) - strtotime($end_times_patient);
    $time = date('i:s', $diff);
   
     if ($time <= 14 ) {
   
    echo 'Time passed';
   
   
   }else{

    call();

   }
    
   } else {
    
    call();
    
function call() {
// something else
```

Whenever I execute the application, this will error occurred. Actually I don't know where I went wrong.
Could someone help me may highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the `call` function is defined *inside* an `else` block?

Comment: @David yes. There are two call( ) functions called inside the else block. When ever becomes false, it should be call the call() function

Comment: But if the function is only *defined* within a given `else` block, wouldn't that mean it's not in scope for the other `else` block?  Why would you define a function inside of an `else` block?  What is the intent for doing that?

Comment: @David When the `if ($time <= 14 ) {` minutes is more than 15 minutes, it should call the call() function. Other thing is  when there is no row in database `if($result10->num_rows > 0){`, it should call  the call ()  function

Answer (score 1):

Refer the documentation for [conditional functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).  You are currently defining a function *inside an `else` block*:

```
if (something) {
  if (something else) {
    //...
  } else {
    call();
  }
} else {
  call();

  function call () {
    //...
  }
}
```

Note the two places in which the `call` function is invoked.  In the second place it's within the same scope that the function is defined, and PHP allows calling a function before it's defined as long as that function is in scope.

But the *first* place in this code where you invoke `call` is in an entirely different scope.  In that case you're inside an `if` block where the function is *defined* in the `else` block.  So by definition any time you try to call that function it won't be defined.

In general, don't conditionally define your functions.  (Not unless you have very good reason to do so and really understand the logic you're using for it.)  Define the function in a higher scope so you can call it in both blocks:

```
if (something) {
  if (something else) {
    //...
  } else {
    call();
  }
} else {
  call();
}

function call () {
  //...
}
```

Comment: If I want to create a `PHP function`, should we need to create a `PHP class`?

Comment: @nasikthaheed: Creating a class isn't necessary in order to create a function, PHP syntax has always allowed the creation of simple global functions.  Classes and OOP are *relatively* recent additions to PHP (they've been around a long time, but not as long as PHP itself has).  Though if you would like to make your code more object-oriented then you are certainly encouraged to start with some tutorials and give it a try.

Comment: @nasikthaheed no, that isn't necessary. Functions can exist outside a class. However you seem to have missed the point of the answer. It's significant _where_ you put the function definition (note we are talking about the _definition_ of the function, not the lines which run the function). If you put the function definition inside an else, as you did, then it cannot be run from outside that else - this explains the error you encountered. Better to put it in the global scope of your code (if you aren't going to use classes).